# In d3.js ticks are not showing in the x axis

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to show a barchart using d3.js. Y axis contains the speed and x axis contains time. I am using the following code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 250 - margin.top;
var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([ 0, width ], .1);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(20);

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.datetime; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.speed; })]);


var svg=d3.select("#bar").append("svg").attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g").attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

   var transition = svg.transition().duration(750), delay = function(d, i) {
    return i * 50;
};
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" ).text("Time");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Speed");

  svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect").transition().delay(0)
      .style("fill", "red")
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { return 30*i+20; })
      .attr("width", 25)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.speed); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.speed); }); //function(d){return " "+d.datetime;}

  transition.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
```

But unfortunately no ticks are showing in the x axis. Y axis ticks are working fine. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your x-axis creation, this:

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" ).text("Time");
```

is just going to but the word "Time" on each tick.  What you need is:

```
// define the time format you want
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
// create x axis
...
.text(function(d){
    return format(d);
});
```

Also in your rect placement:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  ...
  .attr("x", function(d,i) { return 30*i+20; })
```

You are spacing them based on index.  You need to match this to the axis position:

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
  ...
 .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return x(d.datetime);
 })
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6xQV48gA491WqvXJzKVA?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be where you set the domain for x:

```
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.datetime; }));
```

You probably want something like:

```
x.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.datetime; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.datetime; })]);
```